# My question has been marked as on hold. Should I delete it?

Tags: support

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835711) has been marked as off-topic and put on hold. Fair enough. I am asking for something that isn't permitted on stack overflow, to:

> recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other
>   off-site resource

However now when I go to ask another question I'm warned that my account might be banned from asking any more question, which I don't really want to happen. Seeing as my question is in clear breach, and I can't really edit it so that it would not be. Should I just delete it?

Comment: Deleted questions count for a question ban so deleting the bad questions will not help. It is better to improve your existing questions.

Comment: @ArunA.S That's not a good thing in general to do.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker why is that not a good thing to do?

Comment: He's recommending that you leave an off-topic question there without attempting to improve it. That's bad for at least two reasons. 1. It clutters the site with off-topic content, which can encourage other people to ask the same kinds of questions. 2. It's subject to further downvoting.

Comment: I'm sorry that my comment has raised so many problems. It should only apply when the questions are made by simple mistakes. In this case, OP has asked a question recommending a library, and it should be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll bear all of your comments in mind when I next ask a question. Though I don't understand what is wrong with my question here... I am asking a relevant, direct question that has been beneficial to me and surely will for others who have just started asking questions.  How can I improve it so I won't get down-votes?

Comment: @TimothyBuktu , meta votes are different from the main site votes. On meta, an up-vote means they agree with you, and down-vote means they disagree ( or sometimes, they just don't like it and down-vote because it is a simple issue whose solution has already been discussed before and can be found rather easily with a little bit of research  )

Comment: @TimothyBuktu I'm edited my answer to address this specific comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've run into a problem some new users who leap before they look run into:

You've asked a question that you couldn't possibly keep the spirit of and make it fit on Stack Overflow.

So what do you do?

If you delete it, then wherever it's at now, it's there.  It'll count against you with negative votes and not hurt you with positive or no votes.

If you keep it as is, you're going to continue to get downvotes.

So, the only practical thing you can do is edit it so it will reflect an actual problem you have.  In this case, it means fundamentally changing the nature of the question, something we generally frown upon, but in certain cases, makes sense.

In this case, you should do the following.

- read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). All of it.
- Take a look at questions that have more than zero votes.  Emulate those questions. That means: Use good punctuation, spelling, and have a well-defined question that's on topic.
- Continue to research your questions before posting them on Stack Overflow.  We're probably not your first or second 'go to' to get your question answered.  We can't be, not until you understand what questions we accept.
- Once you've done that, edit your question (or delete it) and ask new questions that fit our guidelines.

To address the comment you pose under your question:

> I am asking a relevant, direct question that has been beneficial to me and surely will for others who have just started asking questions. How can I improve it so I won't get down-votes?

That's a common question from users who ask the same sorts of questions you asked: "But this question is useful for others, and I want to know the answer!"

It's not as simple as that. If it were, we wouldn't need Stack Overflow. Forums do this already. Ask anything you want, and you (may) get an answer.

Stack Overflow exists to be a repository of useful, objective programming knowledge. Or put simply, a cookbook for programming problems.  If you need to frob a widget, we can tell you that, so long as the widget and frobbing technique are *well-defined*.

Questions that ask "What should I learn next?" are anything but well-defined.  Even if they are well defined, they run into the next issue; will that knowledge help others?

Even if the answer is yes; then we have to ask:

Is this knowledge being shared? Or opinion?  I can tell you what I think you should do, but it's probably different from what another person would tell you, and so on.  Our format doesn't do that well, by design.

We focus on providing objective answers to actionable programming questions.  If you need something else answered that is programming related, but doesn't fit that criteria, then it doesn't belong here.

Comment: Hm, never knew there were any circumstances in which recycling questions is allowed. Is that new?

Comment: @Deduplicator It depends on the circumstances.

Comment: Ew, this is really coming from a mod? :(

Answer (score 8):

If you can improve the question such that it no longer merits closure, then by all means, do that.  If you are unable to improve the question at all, then yes, go ahead and delete it, just keep in mind that if you continue to post bad questions and delete them, and don't learn from this mistake and improve the quality of your future questions, you may end up being unable to ask questions.

Comment: I can't really edit it to fit within the guidelines, but I definitely found the question useful - I've already bought some of the resources mentioned so I don't really think I should delete it. Are there other areas of the site that would accept more general questions, or it this sort of question just not meant for stack overflow?

Comment: @TimothyBuktu the only place on the network where recommendations are on-topic is SoftwareRecs, and then only within a narrow definition: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic