# On hold - should the process to reopen be changed

Tags: discussion, on-hold

#### Update

I was not aware of some informations from the comments. And my edits did not help to clarify the situation. I changed pieces of my question to adress a few points i did not know before (see below):

#### Edited text

My [question about npm css-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556859/understanding-css-select-on-npm) was put on hold for beeing to broad.

> too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or
>   has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format There
>   are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too
>   long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

This [meta-question about deleting on own on-hold question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291703/) does not fit my problem but the recommendation is to not delete.

- I [still] doubt that the on hold was [needed - but i see that only commenting parts out and adding a self answer worsened the situation]
- Nonetheless, I started to reduce the scope of the question and started to self-answer (a part of the reduced scope) [<-- which likely did add to the confusion]

So my questions / recommendations are:

1. <strike>Should the amount or reputation to be part of reopen a question be lowered to 2000 so that the reopen queue is less of a bottleneck?</strike>
2. <strike>Should an edit bump up a question on the reopen queue?</strike>
3. [EDIT:] We need a link to the result of the reopen review
4. Do you think the on hold was justified - why?

Comment: Not sure if you know this, but the review in the reopen queue for that question was completed [2 days ago with the outcome 3x "Leave closed"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12561500)

Comment: You don't answer your own question in the question itself.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the reopen queue is a bottleneck. There's only 74 questions to divide between the 36,000 potential reviewers that can access it. If an edit bumped a question everybody would be furiously but trivially editing their questions all the time.

Comment: The reopen queue is almost always completly cleared. Reviews in it seldomly take more then a couple hours to complete.

Comment: @Magisch i was not aware of that fact you could see the review status under `/review/reopen/12561500`. Opening the question in another browser still shows on hold. It seems that the review was completed Jun 3 at 11:59  with the result `leave closed`. What puzzles me is that it was on hold for beeing to broad - it was not closed. But based on the  review it seems that on hold is nearly the same thing. Is this the case?

Comment: @Cerbrus i am aware that the answer should not be included inside the question. But since it was on hold i could no longer post an answer. And since the path `/review/reopen/12561500` was unknown to me and still seems to be not linked directly from inside the on-hold-box it thought this would be the only way to address the to broad flag and show that i am willing to improve the question.

Comment: "On Hold" is basically the same as "Closed" here- The only real difference being, besides the name, that a question "On Hold" can be pushed to the reopen queue by an edit.  No, there is no link to the review on your post. That's never been a done on Stack Overflow anyway, so that's not a bug or anything. You _can_ see completed reviews of your posts in the timeline for the post, but you won't get a link to in-progress reviews.

Comment: And I don't suggest just deleting/reposting a question that was closed, even with your improvements. There was [even a Meta question about this recently.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324253/is-there-any-reason-not-to-straight-up-delete-question-and-re-ask-it-if-it-gets)

Comment: @Kendra Where can a find the `timeline for my post`  Regarding your second comment about the question to [straight-up-delete and re-ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324253/) an on hold question. I my opinion there is no black or white answer. If i reduce the scope of a formerly to broad question (to quote ask a `question and mess up`) one could argue that they are not the same questions any longer.  And the review queue did not work since i reduced the scope (ableit only commented out) to two small answer bits - i have answered bigger questions on SO than that.

Comment: The review queue worked in that it put the post before people with the power to reopen the question, those people viewed the question anew, and they still found it wanting. That you disagree with how they reviewed it does not mean the queue did not work. As for the timeline, you have to manually enter the url for it (unless you use a userscript). The format is `stackoverflow.com/posts/{postId}/timeline`. I find it easiest to go to the post's revision history and just change "revisions" to "timeline" in the url.

Comment: @RobertLongson i have no evidence. I had thought that since the question was marked as on hold after more than 2 days that the review had not taken place yet. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: *[EDIT:] We need a link to the result of the reopen review* You can review completed reviews with the timeline.  For example the timeline of your question in the meta post is: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37556859/timeline

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts) user script to get that link on all questions.

Answer (score 8):

I'd still vote "Leave closed":

- You removed some criteria that made it broad by "commenting them out". Don't do that. If it's no longer a criteria, *remove* it.
- The question contains an answer. That doesn't add value to the *question*

If we remove the text that shouldn't be in there, this would be left:

---

> I am trying to understand the npm-package
>
> - [css-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-select) a selector engine
> - [css-what](https://github.com/fb55/css-what) a CSS selector parser
>
> I understand how to use jQuery and their selector engine `var productTitles = $("h2.product")` would return `products` as an array of objects ([irrelevant example][3]).
>
> I do not understand how to use css-select.
>
> ```
> // CSSselect(query, elems, options)
> // Queries elems, returns an array containing all matches.
> // i tried
> CSSselect("h2.products", elems) // <-- which elems are meant?
> ```
>
> My questions are
>
> 1. Can the npm-package css-select be used on the client side?
> 2. Could you provide an example similar to my example above?

---

That is still quite broad.

Comment: I see your point to remove the lines that i commented out. I am aware about the answer in the question - see my comment above about the why. So this leaves q1 which is most likely just a plain `yes` and q2 which could be answered with 2,3 small exmaples. I am quite surprised this is still considered to broad.

Comment: Ugh, the code tags are still broken on meta...

Answer (score 2):

What i have or try to have learned

- reduce the scope by removing pieces not commenting it out
- use the timeline for your post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/{postId}/timeline
- to find out the review link https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/{...id...}/ and to see the review status
- do not confuse people by reducing the scope and start to self answer - [ain't nobdody got time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFEoMO0pc7k) to figure that stuff out (see comment `Do not self-answer a question in the question itself. Post an answer` inside the [review result](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12561500)
- if the result was it should 'stay closed` move on, try to relax otherwise [you will be downvoted into oblivion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324253/)

Comment: _This_ is a good conclusion to come to. My only suggestion is if the result of the reopen review was "stay closed" you _can_ continue to try to improve your post. While it won't go back to review without an explicit reopen vote from someone, it will be bumped in the active tab of the site and get more eyeballs on it that way. (I don't suggest doing small, meaningless edits to bump your post though. That's liable to irritate people.)