# Code blocks in blockquotes render incorrectly (Preview window & answer)

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

I was just writing this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325548/1835379) when I noticed the code block in the blockquote I put in there didn't render properly.

Screenshot:

> [image]

There appears to be some corrupted rules in the style sheets:

> [image]

If I remove the `\9` from those lines, the code block is rendered properly.

Comment: Looks like you're right, @JonasCz. It seems like something that's easy to fix, though...